# How to get the diagonal elements of a covariance matrix from its sparse precision matrix?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a equation to solve $Ax = b$, where $A$ happens to be the precision matrix of a multivariate Gaussian distribution. I can use either direct solver or iterative solvers to get the $x$ vector. However, I also need to get the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix given by $A^{-1}$. I cannot directly invert the sparse precision matrix $A$ since the dimension is very high and its inverse will be full. It won't fit in memory. But I want to get the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix $A^{-1}$. How can I get it?

Comment: Is this related to your question here? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57468/issues-with-solving-large-sparse-linear-equations In general are you totally positive that there isn't something you are trying solve? Usually getting $A^{-1}$ is a bit hard. If you try to replicate a paper you might as well mention it so we might be able to help more substantially. (Also try the http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ you might be pleasantly surprised.)

Answer (score 1):

Solving with $b =$ the $i$'th column of the identity matrix will make the resulting $x =$ the $i$'th column of the covariance matrix. Do that for $i = 1,\dots,n$, each time keeping only the $i$'th element of $x$.